# Application cannot retrieve the package name in signed releases

Tags: android, launch, android-package-managers

```
Intent i;
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
try {
    i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
    if (i == null)
        throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    startActivity(i);
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

After changing the language from inside the application, when I use this code in an unsigned APK then it will work fine.

But when I generate signed APK, the code above does not work.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific error provided, but my answer is based on the assumption that `PackageManager.NameNotFoundException()` is being thrown.

I cannot see the location of the code either, but I'm generally cautious about using `getBaseContext()`. You should be using `getApplicationContext()` to get the package information.

The app can get its own application ID like this:

```
Log.i(TAG, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
```

By default when you create an app in Android Studio, the package name and the application ID are identical. You could use this method if you are struggling for a solution.

Edit:

`BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID` is now deprecated. Use the following instead:

```
BuildConfig.LIBRARY_PACKAGE_NAME
```

But most likely the problem can be solved by using the correct Context with the `PackageManager` rather than using `BuildConfig`.